# When do you need to add a trailing slash to an HTML element?

Tags: html

Consider the following code snippet from [this AngularJS tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/wBhtRLWHIR/6-authenticating-users-with-a-service#item-53044f37605b1ee3e7000016):

```
<div class="auth-forms">

  <h2>Log In</h2>

  <form ng-submit="login()">
    <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"><br>
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </form>

</div>
```

The first two `<input>` tags do not end with a trailing slash but the last one does. I noticed that elsewhere in the tutorial he writes `<br/>` while here he just writes `<br>`. Are there any differences in the two notations and is there a reason why he's written them differently in different locations?

Comment: Basically, very sloppy code. Don't follow that example.

Comment: no reason, except the author lacks consistency.

Comment: are there implications with respect to tools? do they tend to prefer one style over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

The trailing Slash is for `XML` compatibilty, in times of `XHTML`

If you have content, you write:

```
<a href="http://domain.com">Content (Description of the Hyperlink)</a>
```

If you have no Content you write:

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

It is (in `XML`) the same as:

```
<img src="image.jpg"></img>
```

Only `<img>` is not valid `XML`, but `<img />` or `<img></img>` is valid.

**Your Example**

The example you provided is a Mix of `HTML` and `XHTML` Doctype. This is not good style. Either you write `HTML` or you write `XHTML`. Anyway, common Browsers have no Problem with it.